# Help with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Is it ok to ask several questions? There's like a 40 minute wait time before asking another one, I think.

And yes, I did try to read the documentation, but I couldn't really find the information there.

```
\documentclass[jou,11pt]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\title{Title content}
\shorttitle{A short title}
\author{Authors}
\affiliation{Affliated institution}
\leftheader{Author 1}
\abstract{Abstract content}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=RGB Value]
        \addplot table [y=out r, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

        \addplot table [y=out g, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

        \addplot table [y=out b, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ytick={1,2,3,4},
    yticklabels={Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Key},
    ]
    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=43, lower quartile=54,
            median=59,
            upper quartile=62, upper whisker=72,
        },
    ] coordinates {};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=23, lower quartile=33,
            median=37,
            upper quartile=41, upper whisker=51,
        },
    ] coordinates {(0,55)};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=25, lower quartile=37,
            median=41,
            upper quartile=46, upper whisker=58,
        },
    ] coordinates {(0,63)(0,64)(0,67)(0,68)(0,69)};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=0, lower quartile=3,
            median=5,
            upper quartile=8.5, upper whisker=50,
        },
    ] coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

1. The example above produces the error:

> Sorry, could not retrieve column 'out x' from table '
>   \pgfplotstableread@filename@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce
>    name aliases)..

I assume that I should use `\pgfplotstableread` somewhere, but I couldn't find any information on that or any concrete examples.

Sample from .csv file:

```
out x,out r,out g,out b,out c,out m,out y,out k
1,48,51,43,38,28,36,2
2,50,51,44,43,32,38,2
3,55,51,44,47,34,39,3
4,55,54,46,48,35,42,4
5,56,59,47,49,35,43,4
6,58,61,48,50,35,43,5
7,58,63,49,50,36,45,5
8,60,65,49,52,36,46,6
9,61,65,50,52,36,46,6
10,61,65,50,53,36,46,7
```

2. Once the data plot issue is rectified, is there a way to remove the x ticks and labels?
3. Also, how would I ensure that the plot comes out as a smooth curve?
4. Can I change the color of the individual data curves/box plots? How would I do that?
5. The outliers in the box plot are different shapes. Can I change them to be all solid circles like plot 1?

Thank you.

Comment: It is absolutely OK to ask several questions. There is only one thing I'd like to ask you to do: please remove unrelated style files. And if you want to make it more convenient for other users to look at your code, use `filecontents` as in my answer below. Then people only need to copy some code and compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your question:

1. You have to tell `pgfplots` what the column separator is. To this
   end, I added `col sep=comma`.
2. You can remove the ticks by saying `xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty`.
3. To make the curves smooth, add `smooth` to the axis options.
4. Yes, you can change the colors. I added `red` and `cyan`.
5. You can get full circles by saying `mark=*`.

Here's the code (in which I removed unrelated packages):

```
\documentclass[jou,11pt]{apa6}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
%\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fly_data_out.csv}
out x,out r,out g,out b,out c,out m,out y,out k
1,48,51,43,38,28,36,2
2,50,51,44,43,32,38,2
3,55,51,44,47,34,39,3
4,55,54,46,48,35,42,4
5,56,59,47,49,35,43,4
6,58,61,48,50,35,43,5
7,58,63,49,50,36,45,5
8,60,65,49,52,36,46,6
9,61,65,50,52,36,46,6
10,61,65,50,53,36,46,7
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title content}
\shorttitle{A short title}
\author{Authors}
\affiliation{Affliated institution}
\leftheader{Author 1}
\abstract{Abstract content}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,smooth,
    ylabel=RGB Value]
        \addplot table [col sep=comma,y=out r, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

        \addplot[red,mark=*] table [col sep=comma,y=out g, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

        \addplot[cyan,mark=*] table [col sep=comma,y=out b, x=out x]{fly_data_out.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    ytick={1,2,3,4},
    yticklabels={Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Key},
    ]
    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=43, lower quartile=54,
            median=59,
            upper quartile=62, upper whisker=72,
        },
    ] coordinates {};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=23, lower quartile=33,
            median=37,
            upper quartile=41, upper whisker=51,
        },
    ] coordinates {(0,55)};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=25, lower quartile=37,
            median=41,
            upper quartile=46, upper whisker=58,
        },
    ] coordinates {(0,63)(0,64)(0,67)(0,68)(0,69)};

    \addplot+ [
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=0, lower quartile=3,
            median=5,
            upper quartile=8.5, upper whisker=50,
        },
    ] coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]